# IndexError: list index out of range. I cant figure out how to get rid of it

Tags: python

```
dictionary = {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3, "d": 4, "e": 5, "f": 6, "g": 7, "h": 8, "i": 9, "j": 10, "k": 11, "l": 12, "m": 13, "n": 14, "o": 15, "p": 16, "q": 17, "r":18}

word = "redf"
word_list = list(word)

num_of_letters = len(word)
times_looped = 0

while num_of_letters >= times_looped:

    if times_looped <= num_of_letters:

        replacement_num = dictionary.get(word_list[times_looped])
        word_list.pop(times_looped)
        word_list.insert(times_looped, replacement_num)
        times_looped += 1
        print(word_list)
        pass
```

Comment: Why do you need the `if` statement? The `while` condition tests the same thing.

Comment: Side note: Instead of ``pop`` and ``insert`` you could just set the item at position ``times_looped`` directly: ``word_list[times_looped] = replacement_num``

Comment: it is confusing what you want to do with word_list - are you trying to replace with a number/integer or the associated key with the number you get `replacement_num`

Comment: Python lists are zero indexed. This means a list of length 4 has indexes 0, 1, 2, 3. You are trying to get index 4, which is an error. A more pythonic way to do this would be `word_list = [dictionary.get(letter) for letter in word]` which avoids indexes altogether.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is index number that cause out of range conflict between num_of_letters you have assigned and your while loop.

solve this by adding -1 to:

```
num_of_letters = len(word)-1
```

hope this help

Comment: This doesn't seem like great advice. You are suggesting creating a variable named `num_of_letters` this is not actually the number of letters. A better suggesting, if you insist on using indexes, might be changing `>=` to `>`.

Comment: thanks for your attention, maybe I was a little tired :D. 
So the solution i think can to stay `num_of_letters = len(word)` and change `while num_of_letters >= times_looped:` to `while num_of_letters > times_looped:` 
do you agree this??